# Could not load documentdb.spatial.sql

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-cosmosdb, .net-standard

I have a .net 4.7 web application that I pull in my new .netstandard2 libraries.  I am doing this in several applications as we develop our new code.

In this one project i have run into the error below, and in no way or reference or dependency or am I referencing spatial.  the project itself has no references to any spatial namespaces nor does it contain any direct spatial references.

[image]

DocumentDb it self doesnt have any visible dependencies on the documentdb.spatial reference either.

As anybody seen this of solved this issue?

Comment: Please take a look at - Could not load file or assembly 'DocumentDB.Spatial.Sql.dll' or one of its dependencies: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45488291/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-documentdb-spatial-sql-dll-or-one-of-its-depen

Comment: I have previously read SO post.  But ill try the registry fix

Answer (score 1):

The problem ended up being an obsolete reference to the WebActivitor assembly.  This was found out by removing NuGet packages one by one.  There was an old obsolete version and the current version both being referenced and it killed the project when trying to build and flooded the real error handling with non-sense errors.